# How do I customise iTerm terminal to show me (master)?

Tags: terminal, iterm2, iterm, terminal-services

[image]

I download something from Git, it was provided by Linux Academy, I'm just curious, once I got in that folder, in my terminal pops up a word in green (master) and disappears when I get back, I saw that feature before, but from curiosity asking, what kind of plugin is that? I tried to google, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: I would guess the prompt is something set up in your shell/profile. Are you running Bash?

Comment: hi, thanks for respone, i run .zsh, u can git clone the following https://github.com/saaguero/ckad-notes.git and enter in it and u will notice (master) will apprear, i'm just curious, what plugin is that, thanks

Comment: Do you have anything in `~/.zshenv` or `~/.zshrc`? I wonder if `PROMPT` is set in there. Apologies [for a video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nEvsWQrKVcQ), maybe this explains how it is done in your case.